# Cannot instantiate an anonymous class

Tags: java

I am getting 2 errors on this simple piece of code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        O o = new O() {

        };
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
    Test.java:3: cannot find symbol
    symbol  : class O
    location: class Test                                  
    O o = new O() {                               
    ^
```

```
    Test.java:3: cannot find symbol                       
    symbol  : class O                                     
    location: class Test                                  
    O o = new O() {                               
                      ^
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: seems there is no Class defined named "O"

Comment: but isn't it an anonymous class that should work?

Comment: I believe the class should be without name when it's anonymous

Comment: Why did this question get 3 up votes?

Answer (score 3):

With anonymous inner classes you should extend an existing class (and use Polymorphism to override methods) or an existing interface.

With this rule, the code fails since there is NO existing class (type) O.

Try to define the class and use polymorphism to override the methods you want in the parent class.

Answer (score 2):

As the comment says, you have to define the class *somewhere*.  This code should work:

```
class O {}
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        O o = new O() {

        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test  o = new Test () {

        };
        System.out.println(o.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

you will get Test$1

Comment: so what is going to be the 'o'? an object of anonymous class derived from Test?

Comment: It's goin to be a subclass of Test. One without any name. If you debug the code you will see that the name will be something generated ..

Comment: Now the question is if you can find by name this class. Even if it seems it doesn't have a name. (But it has to have one which is suffixed with $1)

Comment: Destination is declared somewhere. Is the same thing.

Comment: You can even do new on an interface. Because you're actually implementing it. Say: Object obj = new Serializable () {};

Comment: these type of questions are typical for SCJP.